# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My question was closed due to being "off topic". But I am curious how my question is different than many other question out there that exist regarding Excel, Access, R, etc were a SuperUser is asking if anyone knows a function or formula they can use. Maybe my examples made it seem like strictly a programming question but that was not my intention.

Here is the link:
[How do I convert Windows Explorer file path to required file path format in R?](https://superuser.com/questions/436920/how-do-i-convert-windows-explorer-file-path-to-required-file-path-format-in-r)

Comment: The **R** programming language is typically used through the command line, like a Bash script, so I don't see why this was closed as off-topic.

Comment: Don't get yourself suspended and migration votes for your questions on other sites don't become close votes.

Answer (score 3):

Let's be clear though: **Nobody wanted to close the question.** The question would have been migrated by five users, plus had a flag sitting on it to move it to Stack Overflow.

We wanted to migrate it there, since in most cases, questions about R have a better home on Stack Overflow, or – if they're about statistical functions – [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Only 22 questions about [r](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/r) have been asked here on Super User. All of them are about installing R rather than really doing anything with it. Stack Overflow has a large R community with over 13000 questions.

Due to some circumstances, the question could not be migrated and was therefore closed. Since at the moment there's no way to ask this on SO, it's okay to keep it here.

Answer (score 0):

The post was reopened by **iglvzx, Bon Gart, nhinkle ♦** at [2012-06-15 00:23:56Z](https://superuser.com/posts/436920/revisions).